# How to change text color based on its result using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change the text color based on its value but I have no clue on how to do that since the values might change.

[image: For example, if the text is 'AABB' then it should have a specific color. If it is 'AABb' it should be another color.]

**For example,** if the text is **'AABB'** then it should have a specific color. If it is **'AABb'** it should be another color ('AABb' = 'AAbB' because the order of the capital letters doesn't matter) and so on...

Here is how these texts (each one is a result) appear on the screen:

```
 body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              '${widget.result} ${widget.result2} ${widget.result3} ${widget.result4} '
              '${widget.result5} ${widget.result6} ${widget.result7} ${widget.result8} '
              '${widget.result9} ${widget.result10} ${widget.result11} ${widget.result12} '
              '${widget.result13} ${widget.result14} ${widget.result15} ${widget.result16} ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 2.5,
                letterSpacing: 0.7,
              ), 
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have text with different styles for different words, you can use RichText, it allows you to divide a text into textSpans that have their own style.
To change the Color based on the input, you can just use a function to get the Color according to the text:

```
Color getTextColor(String text) {
   // Some logic
   return TheRightColor;
}
body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "${widget.result1} ",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: getTextColor(widget.result1),
                      height: 2.5,
                      letterSpacing: 0.7,)),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "${widget.result2} ",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: getTextColor(widget.result2),
                      height: 2.5,
                      letterSpacing: 0.7,))
                ]),
                //...
      )));
```

Also, if you want to simplify the code, you should probably put the widget.result in a list and use a for-loop to display the TextSpans

Comment: The only problem with this code is that there is no space between the results anymore. They are right next to each other.

Comment: Fixed it. You can just put a space at the end of the text spans and it works as needed.